# How to work with MySQLi?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am new on this MySQLi connection. I have system codes here and working on WAMP server localhost. I changed the old mysql connection to new mysqli connection and got rid of these "deprecated errors". But But my problem is that I could not login or access query (sql related function). What I am saying is that I got rid of deprecated errors but could not login/access my database.

//This is my OLD connection:

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("towertec_master") or die(mysql_error());
```

//This is my NEW connection

```
$link = mysqli_connect ("localhost", "root", "", "towertec_master") or die(mysql_error());
```

Also here is my OLD fetch connection:

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT organization_name,address,phone,email FROM system_config");
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);           
$organization_name=stripslashes(trim($row['organization_name']));
$address=stripslashes(trim($row['address']));
$phone=stripslashes(trim($row['phone']));
$email=stripslashes(trim($row['email']));
```

NEW fetch connection:

```
$query = "SELECT organization_name, address, phone, email FROM system_config" or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($link)); 

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
```

Comment: Your `or die...` clause is part of the statement that assigns the query string to `$query`. It should be part of the function call line.

Comment: In your `mysqli_connect()`, you have `or die(mysql_error())` which is the wrong function. Change that to `or die(mysqli_connect_error())`. This is not your immediate problem (as pointed out by @MikeW) but will be a potential future one.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, your are still using the deprecated error function. Also, for your connection, you need to create the connection object which you do with "new".

```
$link = new mysqli_connect ("localhost", "root", "", "towertec_master");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```

For your query, you are putting the error function in the wrong place.

```
$query = "SELECT organization_name, address, phone, email FROM system_config";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query); 
if (!$result) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
}
```